# Why the cookie is not attached when sent a GET request to a different domain using axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I need to attach a cookie for a part of the domain in the URL. To test this I made two domains which is running locally as `localdev1.test.com` and `localdev2.test.com`. In there I am setting a cookie to `.test.com`. When I am sending a simple get request to the same domain it will attach the cookie but when sending for the other domain, it will not attach the cookie. I have given `{withCredentials:true}` . I have used reactJs and node for this. Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this issue?

```
   const transport = axios.create({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        transport
            .get('http://localdev1.test.com:9000/api/messages/sample')
            .then((res)=>{
                alert(res.data.message);
            })
            .catch(err => { /* not hit since no 401 */ })
```

Comment: Can you please post the second request code and a screenshot of the "Cookie" tab of your browsers Developer Tools?

Comment: I have added two screen shots which contains the screen shot of the cookie tab and the code I used to set the cookie. Let's say I am on localdev1.test.com and I am sending request to localdev2.test.com. The screen shots link - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QnzMsptk8qkv3W9GT0BHjB5IPGnM_Isk